Different behaviour between win 10 and win 11 of a python script
The following code works differetly between two PC with identical PY version 3.11.9, identical libraries installed and identical source folder files.
The aim is to open every single excel file in a specified folder, add a line to the first page inserting a specified text and print all sheets but not the first one. all this repeated 4 times per file with different text every time. in win 11 everithing is fine, but on win 10 seems that excel is not closed properly to each cycle so the result is print only the first 4 times with the last one with 4 lines added with all texts. someone can explain me why?
import os
import re
import win32com.client # type: ignore
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, Radiobutton, Entry, Label, Button, IntVar, ttk

# Costanti per gli stili di bordo di Excel e il formato di carta
xlEdgeBottom = 9
xlContinuous = 1
xlPaperA4 = 9  # Formato carta A4
xlLandscape = 2  # Orientamento orizzontale

# Testi per le intestazioni delle 4 copie di stampa
testi_intestazioni = [
    "Text 1",
    "Text 2",
    "Text 3",
    "Text 4"
]

def get_sort_key(filename):
    days = {'LU': 1, 'MA': 2, 'ME': 3, 'GI': 4, 'VE': 5}  # Mappa i giorni a valori numerici
    parts = filename.split('_')
    week = int(parts[-2])
    day = days.get(parts[-1].split('.')[0], 0)
    return (week, day)

def printmanager(cartella, week_filter=None, day_filter=None):
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False  # Imposta Excel non visibile durante l'esecuzione

    try:
        files_to_print = [f for f in os.listdir(cartella) if f.endswith(('.xls', '.xlsx'))]
        files_to_print.sort(key=get_sort_key)

        files_printed = 0  # Contatore per tracciare il numero di file stampati

        for filename in files_to_print:
            # Creazione di un pattern di ricerca per la settimana che isola esattamente il numero inserito
            if week_filter:
                week_pattern = fr'WK_{week_filter}_'  # Assicura che il pattern includa W seguito dalla settimana e underscore
                if not re.search(week_pattern, filename):
                    continue
            
            if day_filter:
                # Assumi che i giorni siano indicati nel filename con _LU, _MA, ecc.
                day_pattern = f'_{day_filter}'
                if day_pattern not in filename:
                    continue
            
            full_path = os.path.join(cartella, filename)
            workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(full_path)

            for i in range(4):
                workbook.Sheets(1).Copy(After=workbook.Sheets(1))
                copied_worksheet = workbook.Sheets(2)
                copied_worksheet.Rows("1:1").Insert()
                copied_worksheet.Columns("Z:Z").Hidden = True
                copied_worksheet.Columns("U:U").Hidden = True
                merged_cell = copied_worksheet.Range("A1:Z1")
                merged_cell.Merge()
                copied_worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = testi_intestazioni[i]
                copied_worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Font.Name = "Arial"
                copied_worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Font.Size = 35
                copied_worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
                copied_worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Font.Color = 255  # RGB for Blue

                # Configurazione della stampa
                copied_worksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
                copied_worksheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
                copied_worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
                copied_worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False

                copied_worksheet.PrintOut()
                workbook.Sheets(2).Delete()

                files_printed += 1  # Incrementa il contatore di file stampati

            workbook.Close(False)

        excel.Quit()
        if files_printed == 0:
            messagebox.showwarning("Attenzione", "Nessun file disponibile per i filtri selezionati.")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Successo", "Stampa completata con successo.")
    except Exception as e:
        excel.Quit()
        messagebox.showerror("Errore", f"Si è verificato un errore: {e}")

def start_gui():
    def start_printing():
        choice = print_option.get()
        week = week_entry.get().strip()
        day = day_entry.get()  # Ottieni il valore dal Combobox
        if choice == 1:
            printmanager(source_folder)
        elif choice == 2:
            printmanager(source_folder, week_filter=week if week else None)
        elif choice == 3:
            printmanager(source_folder, week_filter=week if week else None, day_filter=day if day else None)


    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("DMS - Doors Print Manager")
    root.geometry("600x300")

    print_option = IntVar(value=1)
    Radiobutton(root, text="Stampa tutti i file", variable=print_option, value=1, font=("Helvetica", 12), fg="blue").pack(anchor='c')
    Radiobutton(root, text="Stampa file per settimana", variable=print_option, value=2, font=("Helvetica", 12), fg="magenta").pack(anchor='c')
    Radiobutton(root, text="Stampa file per giorno specifico", variable=print_option, value=3, font=("Helvetica", 12), fg="black").pack(anchor='c')

    separator = ttk.Separator(root, orient='horizontal')
    separator.pack(fill='x', padx=10, pady=10)

    Label(root, text="Inserisci settimana (WW):", font=("Helvetica", 12)).pack()
    week_entry = Entry(root)
    week_entry.pack()

    # Opzioni per il giorno
    Label(root, text="Seleziona giorno:").pack()
    # Elenco dei giorni della settimana
    days = ['LU', 'MA', 'ME', 'GI', 'VE']
    day_entry = ttk.Combobox(root, values=days, state="readonly")
    day_entry.pack()
    day_entry.set('Seleziona un giorno')  # Testo predefinito

    Button(root, text="Inizia Stampa", command=start_printing, font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), fg="green").pack(pady=10)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Imposta il percorso della cartella sorgente dei file Excel
    source_folder = r"\\path"
    start_gui()


I tried multiple ways to try to close excel in other ways, always work in win 11 but none in win 10.

What versions of Excel are involved? In any case, please provide a [mcve]. Anyhow, it "seems that excel is not closed" is just your personal interpretation, but what are the actual observations (verifyable facts) that brought you to that?

I say excel is not closed because contrary to what happens in win 11, in win 10 after the last print command appears all the saving windows of excel asking what to do (save or don't save). Based on the code it should close without saving after every print

Almost forgot, Excel is on both PC same version, 2308 (same build)

It is worth running your tests after checking there are no existing (possibly background) Excel processes using Task Manager. Sometimes you can have a session in the background of which you were unaware.
